# "Your administrator has not installed Web Add-ins for your organization" when try to add Office Add-in for SharePoint 2016 + Office Online Server

Tags: excel, sharepoint, office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins

**My environment:**

- 1st VM/server: Active Directory Domain Controller
- 2nd VM/server: SharePoint 2016 On-Premises
- 3rd VM/server: Office Online Server (old Office Web Apps) also
  On-Premises - version from November 2017

**Done already:**
Communication between SharePoint and OOS. I have also custom Office Excel Add-in uploaded to Apps for Office list in App Catalog site. Add-in itself should be fine - it works in other environment.

**Issue:**
When I try to install add-in in Excel in web/browser, I'm getting "Your administrator has not installed Web Add-ins for your organization" message:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/petDY.png)

I have got also uploaded Office Excel Add-in to Apps for Office list in App Catalog, and it still does not work. Did I miss something in the configuration to allow adding custom add-ins?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a sharepoint catalog and app store add-ins are mixed in you post.

Instead of uploading the add-in Office 365, under Setting>Service & add-ins, try uploading the add-in in SharePoint Online Add Catalog site. To do this, please follow the steps below:

1. Sign in to Office 365 portal with admin credentials.
2. Go to Admin Center>SharePoint Online Admin Center.
3. Once you are in SharePoint Admin center, go to App Catalog site, URL should be something like https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/AppCatalog
4. Click Apps for Office on the left navigation panel to upload the add-in for Office apps.
5. Click Upload and browser the path where the custom add-in is saved on your system.

See [Excel does not show Office 365 custom add-in](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-does-not-show-office-365-custom-add-in/9776d60e-5047-4d59-af4c-1dafeaa5a6d5?auth=1) for more information

Comment: Eugene Astafiev, I saw that post already, but I don't use SharePoint Online or Office 365.

I have updated my question with more details about the environment now.

Comment: I think you have mixed SharePoint and Office add-ins at some point.

Comment: What do you mean? I want to allow installing Office add-ins in web/browser, so Excel document opened in browser from SharePoint list.

That is why I am using Office Online Server: to open Office docs in browser, directly from SharePoint list (instead of desktop app). At the same time I want to instlal for that docs openend in browser, Office Add-ins uploaded to SharePoint AppCatalog.